# Restrict sitecore publishing

Tags: security, sitecore, publishing, sitecore7.2

I am trying to set up some restrictions within my Sitecore instance so that users who only have permission to create items within a subsection of a site also have the publish permission, but only have the ability to publish items where they have create content permission.

For example I have the content similar to the following:

```
Sitecore
|- Content
    |- Home
        | - WhatWeDo
            | - Infrastructure
            | - Training
        | - Locations
            | - Europe
            | - North America
```

I have set up the Everyone role to have read permission to all items within the content tree, and I have specifically specified that they are denied write, rename, create, and delete permission

I have set up a role, "WhatWeDo" and has been granted write, rename, create, and delete permission to item WhatWeDo and its descendants.

Now if I add the "WhatWeDo" role to the Client Publishing role, then the users who have been granted "WhatWeDo" role, also have the ability to publish, but they have the ability to publish any item within the content tree. i.e. The Publish button on the Publish ribbon is displayed.

Mostly when I have tried googling this, they are talking about publishing restrictions. i.e the Publishing Settings dialog, but this is of no use to me in this scenario.

I have found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6351649/1442308 but I cannot seem to get this working and I suspect that it is related to very old version of Sitecore and no longer applies.

I have also updated my config so that the publishing should only publish if have read and write permission

```
  <setting name="Publishing.CheckSecurity" > 
    <patch:attribute name="value" value="true" />
  </setting>
```

But this has had no effect on restricting users publishing content tree items that they should not as the user is still able to publish items within the Locations section of the content tree. i.e. The publish button is still visible on the Publish ribbon.

I need to restrict this so that those users who have been granted the "WhatWeDo" role can only publish item WhatWeDo and its descendants, and do not have the ability to publish any other item within the content tree. i.e They should only have the publish button visible when they are in the WhatWeDo item or any of its descendants.

**Update**

Updated question to make it clearer that I want to make sure that the publishing button is not visible on the ribbon bar.

Answer (score 5):

The Publishing.CheckSecurity setting is used durring the execution of the publish, so only items that the user has access to are actually published.  It does not affect access to the publish ribbon button.

Typically, people use workflow to achieve what you are looking for.  Set up a workflow with a publish action.  The sample workflow provided with the initial install gives an example of this.  Then you can restrict access to the workflow command.

**Update**

The Sample Workflow that is provided out-of-the-box has everything you need to get this to work.  It has the commands and the auto-publish action as well as the security settings applied for the Sitecore Client Authoring role.

[image: sample workflow security]

Since you have already applied security to your content items, all you would need to do is assign those items to the sample workflow. You could duplicate it and rename it if you wanted. You could also rename the Approve command to Publish.

To ensure that the standard publish button does not appear in the ribbon, make sure that these users are not members of the Sitecore Client Publishing role.

Comment: I am looking to have the publish button on the ribbon hidden if the user should not be publishing. I have done a few tests. For the user who has been given the "WhoWeAre" role, they have the Publish button visible for the Locations items. A user can publish this item, and unless they expand to show more info on the completion dialog, they wont see the message that the item was skipped. Most users will just assume that the item was published, and will then wonder why they cannot see their changes on the live site.

Comment: You really can't do that with the standard publish button.  The visibility of the publish ribbon button is controlled by the permissions on its definition item in the core database.  It does not look at the item selected in the content editor.  It is better to just not give users access to that button and use workflow instead.

Comment: I think @BenGolden is right. You cannot really pick and choose who sees the Publish button based on what sections they have access to. 

1. Create a Rules Engine custom rule that accomplishes what you want.
2. Create a simple workflow with two states (Draft and Approved) and one action to Publish on the Draft state. You then add this workflow to each and every template you need the publish button on. After that you create a role called publisher and grant permissions on this workflow. Any person who needs to publish should have this role. 

If you like I can provide details for 2nd option

Comment: @Gabbar if you could provide the details. For reasons that are too long to go into i need a solution that uses out of the box. I cannot make any code changes to this solution at present. thanks

Comment: Thanks for that. I now have something that I have gone back to my client to discuss. Now just waiting for their feedback

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry but I don't have the comments option enabled yet.)

I would definitely go for the workflows option. As mentionned in the comments, the Publish button will be enabled through the security permissions, but as a general ability, not dependent on the items permissions. If you don't want the Publish button to show up without going into fancy customizations, you should forget this option.

Instead of the classical Publish button, users would have the workflow button triggering the publish action, under the Review tab. It wouldn't change that much for your end-users. It will even get them used to the workflow actions, that you could further use and refine, later in your project. You could take this opportunity to introduce them in your project, moreover it's perfectly suiting your needs.

Don't hesitate to ask if you want more detailed explanations on how to set up such a workflow.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible hide the publish button in the ribbon out of the box for items that the user does not have access to, but it is quite simple to use the Rules Engine to control whether the button is shown or not. It will require some coding though, there is no way around that.

You can find more information in these blog posts, but there are some differences for Sitecore 7.1+ due to changes in the Rules Engine:

- [Rule-Based User Interface Components for the Sitecore Client](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/getting-to-know-sitecore/posts/2012/10/rule-based-user-interface-components-for-the-sitecore-client.aspx)
- [How to create a custom ribbon in Sitecore Content Editor](http://reyrahadian.com/2015/12/17/how-to-create-a-custom-ribbon-in-sitecore-content-editor/)
- [Limiting Conditions and Actions with Sitecore 7.1+](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/getting-to-know-sitecore/posts/2013/11/limiting-conditions-and-actions-with-sitecore-71.aspx)

**1. Create the rule action class**

In your Visual Studio Project create the `CommandRuleContext` and `SetCommandState` classes as specified in first blog post.

**2. Create the Rule in Sitecore**

This is where there have been a lot of updates in Sitecore 7.1+, the third blog post explains the new structure of the rules engine:

1. Under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Tags` create a new tag called `Command State`
2. Under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions` create a new folder called `Command States` and add the 4 states shown in Step 1.14
3. Create a new Element Folder under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Elements` called `Command Rules`
4. Insert a new `Action` under this folder. Set the field values as:

   **Text:** `set command state to [commandstateid,Tree,root=/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Definitions/Command States,specific command state]`

   **Type:** `MyProject.Custom.Commands.SetCommandState, MyProject.Custom`
5. Select the `Tags/Default` item and select `Command State` from the list of tags. This is the tag we defined earlier.
6. Now under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules` insert a new "Rules Context Folder" called `Command Rules` and then add a new rule in the Rules folder.
7. Before we create the rule we need to associate tags to show the conditions and actions. Select the "Tags/Default" item again and this time select `Command State` and `Item Security`. You can select different tags if you want to use different conditions (e.g. Item Hierarchy, Item Information, Security etc)
8. Now create the rule with condition you need, e.g.

[image: Rule Description]

**3. Update the command to use the Rules**

We need to update the code for the Publish button command to use the Rules we have defined.

Create a new command class inheriting from the existing Publish command:

```
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.Rules;
using Sitecore.SecurityModel;
using Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands;

namespace MyProject.Custom.Commands
{
    public class PermissionBasedPublish : Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.PublishNow
    {
        public override CommandState QueryState(CommandContext context)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull(context, "context");
            var state = base.QueryState(context);
            if (state != CommandState.Enabled)
                return state;

            return RunRules(context);
        }

        private CommandState RunRules(CommandContext context)
        {
            Item parentRuleItem;

            var ruleContext = new CommandRuleContext();
            ruleContext.Item = context.Items[0];

            using (new SecurityDisabler())
            {
                parentRuleItem = ruleContext.Item.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Command Rules/Rules");
                if (parentRuleItem == null)
                    return CommandState.Enabled;
            }

            RuleList<CommandRuleContext> rules = RuleFactory.GetRules<CommandRuleContext>(parentRuleItem, "Rule");

            if (rules == null)
                return CommandState.Enabled;

            rules.Run(ruleContext);
            return ruleContext.CommandState;
        }
    }
}
```

And now we can patch in this command instead of the default one:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
  <sitecore>
    <commands>
      <command name="item:publishnow">
        <patch:attribute name="type">MyProject.Custom.Commands.PermissionBasedPublish, MyProject.Custom</patch:attribute>
      </command>
    </commands>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

The visibility of the publish button is now based on defined rules. With the rule defined above, the button will only be visible if the user has write access to the current item they are one.

The user will still need publish permission using the appropriate roles. Note that using out of the box roles means the user will have access to the Publish Site option from the drop down as well. You need to restrict access to `/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Menues/Publish/Publish Site` in the Core database and the shortcut from the desktop as appropriate.

You may also want to combine this with the `Publishing.CheckSecurity` setting by setting it to **true**.

I'll add that giving users Publish rights as a general rule is a bad idea IMO since every publish, even of a single item (and this includes Auto-Publish with Workflow) will clear the HTML caches and may lead to performance issues.

Comment: Thanks for this. It is very detailed will try and keep it in my tooklit for future reference. This link http://chowson.github.io/security-based-publishing-restrictions-in-sitecore/ shows another way of hiding the publish button based on write permissions.

Comment: Hadn't seen that before, it's essentially the same solution, except the logic is hard baked in code. The Rules Engines allows greater flexibility to add exceptions or make changes.